# Synchronized List/Map in Java if only one thread is writing to it

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, synchronized, java.util.concurrent

The first thread is filling a collection continuously with objects. A second thread needs to iterate over these objects, but it will not change the collection.

Currently I use `Collection.synchronized` for making it thread-safe, but is there a fast way to doing it?

### Update

It's simple: The first thread (ui) continuously writes the mouse position to the ArrayList, as long as the mousebutton is pressed down. The second thread (render) draws a line based on the list.

Comment: If you are not worried  that your second thread might not have received the "latest" data, you don't need synchronisation..

Comment: So the first thread is responsible to remove the items also?

Comment: Are you saying that the collection will continuously grow, since there's one thread adding and another thread re-iterating it? So the first object will be iterated N times?

Comment: Even a synchronized list is not thread-safe if you iterate on it without explicit synchronization.

Comment: Can you find a way to make it so the second thread only needs to see the new objects? That way you could use a blocking queue just to communicate the new data the second thread.

Comment: its ok, if the second thread don't get the latest data. The objects will never be removed. The first thread will only give up his reference on the List and stop filling it.

Comment: maybe check out persistent data structures. structural sharing is a lot better than synchronizing or copyonwrite.

Comment: This sounds much like a task where you would like a queue more than a list and there you would have the ConcurrentLinkedQueue where you do not need to worry about locking.

Comment: @jozzy, There's more to synchronization than just "receiving the latest data."  From the OP's question, we don't even know what _kind_ of collection, much less how the collection is implemented.  It's entirely possible that if one thread is iterating over the collection while another thread is updating it, that could cause the iterating thread to see the collection in an invalid state, and lead to a program crash.

Comment: it looks like a producer-consumer pattern. A structure that is well suited for this is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you synchronize the list, it's not necessarily thread-safe while iterating over it, so make sure you synchronize on it:

```
synchronized(synchronizedList) {
    for (Object o : synchronizedList) {
        doSomething()
    }
}
```

#### Edit:

Here's a very clearly written article on the matter: 
http://java67.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-synchronize-arraylist-in-java.html

Answer (score 3):

Use java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.ArrayBlockingQueue implementation of BlockingQueue. It perfectly suits your needs.

1. It is perfectly suited for producer-consumer cases as that is one in yours.
2. You can also configure access policy. Javadoc explains access policy like this:

   > Fair if true then queue accesses for threads blocked on insertion or removal, are processed in FIFO order; if false the access order is unspecified.

Comment: that's the one I was looking for. definitely better that the deque I linked.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you need explicit synchronization on this list, because iteration is not atomic:

```
List<?> list = // ...
```

Thread 1:

```
synchronized(list) {
    list.add(o);   
}
```

Thread 2:

```
synchronized(list) {
    for (Object o : list) {
        // do actions on object
    }
}
```

Comment: And I don't need to use Collection.synchronized... ?

Comment: @doev if you perform just these 2 operations, you don't

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 options which I can currently think of to handle concurrency in ArrayList:-

1. Using Collections.synchronizedList(list) - currently you are using it.
2. CopyOnWriteArrayList - behaves much like ArrayList class, except that when the list is modified, instead of modifying the underlying array, a new array in created and the old array is discarded. It will be slower than 1.
3. Creating custom ArrayList class using ReentrantReadWriteLock. You can create a wrapper around ArrayList class. Use read lock when reading/iterating/looping and use write lock when adding elements in array. 
   For e.g:-

   ```
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
   import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;
   import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

   public class ReadWriteList<E> {

       private final List<E> list;
       private ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
       private final Lock  r =lock.readLock();
       private final Lock  w =lock.writeLock();

       public ReadWriteList(List<E> list){
           this.list=list;
       }

       public boolean add(E e){

           w.lock();
           try{
               return list.add(e);
           }
           finally{
           w.unlock();
           }
       }

       //Do the same for other modification methods

       public E getElement(int index){
           r.lock();
           try{

               return list.get(index);
           }
           finally{
               r.unlock();
           }   
       }

       public List<E> getList(){
           r.lock();
           try{
           return list;
           }
           finally{
           r.unlock();
           }   
       }
       //Do the same for other read methods
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading far more often than writing, you can use [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Comment: In some situations CopyOnWriteArrayList is surely an option. Thx

Comment: The OP said, "The first thread is filling a collection continuously with objects."  That is absolutely the _worst_ use-case for `CopyOnWriteArrayList.`  The time complexity for adding N elements to a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is O(N^2).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a `List` will a `Set` suit your needs?

If so, you can use `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>())`